# Are emails sent from ProtonMail to Tutanota (or vice versa) ever not encrypted?

Tags: encryption, protonmail

Both mail accounts, ProtonMail and Tutanota are encrypted, and as the knowledge base from ProtonMail states, ‘emails from ProtonMail users to non-ProtonMail users’ are ‘otherwise encrypted with TLS if the non-ProtonMail mail server supports it’.

So, since the email is encrypted at both ends, at ProtonMail and at Tutanota, and is encrypted with TLS during transport, can the email ever be intercepted and read in plain text at any stage in this case?

Additional Information

I've found [a site](https://ssl-tools.net/mails) where it says:

> "Test mail delivery. Does your mailserver use an encrypted connection
> (STARTTLS) to send mails to our server? Just send an empty email
> (check@ssl-tools.net) and check the result".

And these are the results:

```
from ***@tutanota.com - TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - Host: w1.tutanota.de (81.3.6.162)
```

and

```
from ***@protonmail.com  - TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - Host: mail-40130.protonmail.ch (185.70.40.130)
```

I don't have enough know-how to interpret this, but it appears to me that the mails were sent with encryption.

And for anybody that knows what they are looking at, here are two more pages that seem to have information regarding my question, which I am not capable to interpret myself:
[ssl-tools.net/mailservers/protonmail.ch](https://ssl-tools.net/mailservers/protonmail.ch) and [ssl-tools.net/mailservers/tutanota.com](https://ssl-tools.net/mailservers/tutanota.com)

Comment: As far as I know, an email that is sent from Protonmail to Prontonmail is encrypted at any stage. An email that is sent from Protonmail to non-Protonmail is only encrypted at transport if mailserver supports and it's plaintext on this server.

Comment: Protonmail supports PGP with non-Protonmail users, but it has to be explicitly setup. See: https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/how-to-use-pgp/ . Without tthis external PGP setup, I would expect clear text conversion at some point on both servers.

Comment: I agree with the other commenters.  The post you are referring to is: https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/what-is-encrypted/.  It specifically states that most mail providers (e.g. Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail) support TLS, but this is not end-to-end encryption - i.e. "this means Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, etc, will be able to read these messages and hand them over."

Comment: I know about Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, ect. I am not talking about them. I am purely interested in what happens between ProtonMail and Tutanota. They are both encrypted email providers, and neither of them is supposed to be able to read your mail.So the question is not what happens on their servers, but what happens during tranport. Are the mails encrypted with TLS on-route if the password protection is not specifically selected?

Comment: TLS in email providers is basically plaintext to some attackers. If you want security you need to encrypt the message contents with your recipients public key. Don't trust what a vendor tells you about their level of security, implement something that meets your standards which you have control over.

Comment: @john doe This is probably good advise. But could you explain your first sentence a bit further? Is it because TLS is generally a week form of encryption, or because email providers don't implement it properly, or...?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here, because you provide the answer to your own question in the first paragraph. And we cannot specify what *might* happen or what misconfigurations there might be. Emails *might* get sent unencrypted and not over TLS to any recipient if an error occured.

Comment: @questionmark Mail sent from Protonmail to Tutanota is akin to mail sent from Protonmail to Gmail.  Tutanota has access to plaintext messages sent from Protonmail users to Tutanota users - just as Gmail has access to plaintext messages sent from Protonmail users to Gmail users.  In both cases, the SMTP connection between the two providers is over TLS, so the messages are encrypted in transit between the two providers.  But it's not end-to-end encryption, because ProtonMail does not have Tutanota's users' public keys.

Comment: Thank you both, schroeder and mti2935, for answering/confirming my question/guess.  
My concern was not so much security, but privacy. I have no great secrets to keep, but I am tired of the constant invasion of privacy, especially by Google. It also feels good to know that the email cannot be readily intercepted as plain text in transit. It's convinced me that it is worth spending a few Euro on a tutanota account, although I know nobody with either, tutanota or protonmail.